# How to extend tinymce's media plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE already has a bunch of nice plugins out of the box. One of them - media plugin - wich i would like to extend.

[image]

**Problem**: I use an exterenal Video service with an API. In order to play video on the page, i need to embed it with an `iframe`. The iframe-code - especialy the `src`-attribute - can be generated *only* on the server by specific `page_id` and `video_id` and some other data from database. So whoever tries to embed a video from that particular video-service needs an already generated `iframe-block` or at least a generated `url` and that is the problem.

**Goal:** Somehow extend tinymce' functionality. Ideally the "media" plugin.
I would like to add either a new input-field to **"General"** tab or create a separate tab with additional input fields. Something like that:

[image]

or

[image]

**Question:** What would be the best (or simplest) way to achive this ?

Answer (score 2):

The best, and only, way to achieve this is to edit the code (`plugin.js`) of the media plugin (the non-minified files can be downloaded here https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce)

Adding a tab and fields to the interface can be done by extending the tabpanel (in the file around line 155). And furthermore writing the code to submit your fields to the editor. I have worked with plugins in tinymce before and must say it can be a complicated matter.

A very short introduction on plugins in tinymce can be found here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin

Good luck!